# add css in shopify custom app using remix template?

Tags: css, shopify, remix, custom-application

How to add css in shopify custom app using remix template ?

I am expecting app/routes/main/products.jsx is over components and routes over need is how to load css in particular components any working method accept but try best thing to add css.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will assist you to include css in your remix-app

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/styling/css

Please read some docs or watch some YouTube videos, instead of asking basic questions here.